# Beamer - align with LHS and RHS replacement

Tags: beamer, align, overlays

I'm writing an presentation of the project where I took a "standard" equation and modified it slightly. I would like to therefore show this by replacing the standard equation with its modified version.

I've seen a few solutions here, but they all deal with RHS replacements and don't work with the LHS.

I would like (this is merely as an example)

`A &= B`

to be replaced by

`A + C &= B^D`

while maintaining the alignment around the equations. I've tried using

`\alt<2->{A + C}{A} &= \alt<2->{B^D}{B}`

but while `\alt` solves RHS replacement (especially if used with `\phantom` to deal with possible vertical erros), with a variable LHS the result still wobbles. How can this be solved?

Comment: The suggested duplicate is entirely valid. For the record, I adopted Henry DeYoung's solution, since it allows the LHS to be right-aligned. The others leave the above LHS in the first slide as `A   = B`.